# Quit the loop if encounter error message

Tags: performance-tuning, options, procedural-programming, system

First define **length-component** error (personal term) :
This is an error when we want to get n-th component of a list if n is bigger then the length of the list. For example, `Range[5][[7]]` yields `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}[[7]]` but with an **error message**.

Is there an option (I mean `SetOptions`) to quit the loop, if length-component error occurs?
(*Or any kind of error that yields an error message*)

You can understand my question easily with screenshots. There are three codes.
Note that `MyList = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};` for all 3 codes.
If you think the best is Code 2, I would appreciate it if you wrote so.

**Code 1 :**

[image]

**Code 2 :**

[image]

**Code 3 :**

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To exit evaluation when a message is encountered, use `Enclose` together with `ConfirmQuiet`:

```
In[121]:= Enclose[n = 1; 
 While[n < 10, Print[ConfirmQuiet[MyList[[n]]]]; ++n]]

During evaluation of In[121]:= 1

During evaluation of In[121]:= 2

During evaluation of In[121]:= 3

During evaluation of In[121]:= 4

During evaluation of In[121]:= 5

Out[121]= Failure["ConfirmationFailed", <|...|>]
```

Comment: Thank you! As my wish, the answer is not about ignoring messages. CPU really stops when it encounters error message.

Answer (score 3):

Loops are seldom used in MMA. Most of the time loops ca be avoided and replaced by more efficient constructs. However, if you insist on using loops:

At the start of the loop you already know the length of the list. Therefore create a loop with a fixed number of repetitions. Use Do or For. E.g. using Do:

```
list = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
Do[Print[list[[i]]], {i, Length[list]}]
```

Or with For:

```
For[i = 1, i <= Length[list], i++ , Print[list[[i]]]]
```

Comment: Thank you, in fact what I wanted is hard to do with `Do`.. it is hard to know when it ends. I simplified the example to make it easier to ask.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
n = 1; While[n < 10, If[MemberQ[Outer[List, Ordering[MyList]], {n}] ===True, Print[MyList[[n]]], Break[]]; ++n]
```

[image]